# Перехват смс сообщений

Tags: android, sms

Добрый день.
Хочу перехватывать смс сообщение. При выполнении определенных условий не хочу что бы сообщение появлялось в стандартном мессенджере.

```
final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED);
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new IncomingSMSReceiver();
filter.setPriority(100);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

В ресивере

```
public class IncomingSMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String queryString = "@echo";
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    public String to;
    public String msg;
    public int count=0;

    public void onReceive(Context _context, Intent _intent) {
        if (_intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
           ..............
        if(condition) abortBroadcast();

        }
    }
}
```

В рессивере сообщение получаю, обрабатываю, но основной мессенджер все равно получает сообщение.

---

Еще покопался по этой теме. 
As of Android 1.6, incoming SMS message broadcasts (android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED) are delivered as an "ordered broadcast"
У меня API21
Пробовал Включать рессивер как в коде так и через Манифест.
Так же где-то прочитал что на выполнение abortBroadcast() отводится немного времени, около 250мс. Ради теста перенес abortBroadcast() в самое начало onReceive. Но дефолтный менеджер все так же собирает смс.
Так же на всякий случай проверил на двух разных телефонах. Правда на обоих android5.1

Comment: Попробуйте повысить приоритет `filter.setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`

Comment: @tosh17 увас condition не true  видимо, что бы не пробрасывалось дальше, наддо делать abortBroadcast() и `<intent-filter android:priority="99999999">` или как выше указали

Comment: если честно то я пробовал без if. не помогало. повысил приоритет как советовал  eugeneek. Тоже не помогло.
В разных статьях читал противоположные вещи.
В одной что дефолтное приложение получит сообщение в любом случае. В другом что у дефолтного приоритет 0 и перехватить нет проблем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тот способ, что вы используете, работает только до версии **Android 4.4** (***API Level 19***). Начиная с **Android 4.4** вы не сможете заблокировать от получения *SMS* сообщений, установленным по умолчанию. Вариант, как сделать свое приложение получалкой *SMS* сообщений по умолчанию, опписан в [блоге разработчиков](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).